# Enviar correo por SMTP usando TLS Genexus

Tags: genexus, smtp, javamail

Cordial Saludo,

GX 16U9 Generador Java.
Estoy intentando enviar correo desde una conexión por TLS y veo que hay inconvenientes para hacer este envío con Java y SMTPSession. Hay un SAC que plantea una posible solución con JavaMail, pero no es muy clara.

El reporte del error:
https://www5.genexus.com/xev3/scmain.aspx?P%3B178%3B94%3B1264%3B1%3B1%3BO%3B,33259;;

La posible solucion que no es muy clara:
https://www5.genexus.com/xev3/scmain.aspx?S%3B178%3B94%3B1264%3B1%3B1%3BO%3B,33666

Mi error al intentar enviar correo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del código usado:

```
&SMTPSession.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com '
&SMTPSession.Sender.Name = 'Correo Institucional'
&SMTPSession.Sender.Address = 'correo_prueba@gmail.com'
&SMTPSession.Timeout = 60
&SMTPSession.Authentication = 1
&SMTPSession.Secure = 1 
&SMTPSession.Port = 465
```

En espera de comentarios,

Muchas Gracias

Comment: algunos comentarios... Por un lado, en la versión en la que estás trabajando ya utilizas "por debajo" JavaMail como implementación. Por otro lado, creo que el problema pueda estar en el puerto que estás indicando. Por defecto el puerto 465 utiliza SSL y para TLS deberías utilizar por defecto el puerto 587. ¿Podrías probar con el puerto 587 y ver si te funciona?

Comment: Hola Marce...gracias por tu respuesta. Al usar 587 con secure 0 y secure 1, obtengo el siguiente error Error sending message - 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g139sm1046769vke.17 - gsmtp, siguiendo el SAC #26996: Error al enviar email via Gmail y tambien aplique el siguiente SAC #33666: JavaMail is added as a new way of managing emails for the Java generator , pensando que era el ceritificado, pero no, persiste el error....

Comment: ¿Tienes la posibilidad de probar el envío de mail simplemente en un proc pero en v17u6?

Comment: Hola Marce...no me es posible probar con esta versión. Estuve haciendo pruebas con un correo de hotmail y este si funciono, utlizando puerto 25. Con Gmail aun persiste el error, no se si sea algo con los certificados.

Comment: lograste solucionar esto?
Es que tengo el mismo incoveniente con la genexsu 17 U9/Java 11

Comment: Si, utilice gmail usando los mismos parametros, lo que hice diferente fue configurar en Gmail la autenticación en dos pasos y habilitar la contraseña de aplicaciones, esto genera una contraseña y esta la configuré como parametro.

Comment: @JoséArmando me alegra que encontraras una solución al problema. Por favor, añade una respuesta en la publicación para que otros usuarios puedan aprovecharla y les sea de ayuda si tienen el mismo problema. Lee [answer] para más información.